# Store data in a array and search for items

Tags: php

I Connect to a `remote SSH` device in `Php`.
I run a `command` that output is too long.
So I searched and understood I can save it via :

```
   $my_array= explode("\n", $this->ssh->exec('some command'));
```

Its ok, Now I can display whole output via :

```
echo print_r($my_array);
```

Output is something like :

```
Array ( [0] => ath4_auth_mode=disabled [1] => wl_mac_deny= [2] => filter_dport_grp3= [3] => ses_script= [4] => http_redirect_port=3128 [5] => oet5_en=0 [6] => filter_dport_grp4= [7] => oet2_fragment=0 [8] =>
```

When I run :

```
echo count($my_array);
```

It displays me :

```
2200
```

So it is true, Now I wanna search for a specific text like `name=`,I want the value after equal in the array, I tried this :

```
           $search_result = array_search("name=", $my_array);
```

But no chance, Even tried :

```
foreach($my_array as $cat) {
$cat = trim($cat);
if($cat == "name=") { 
    echo "hoola !";
} else { 
    echo ':-(';
}
```

Again no chance, How can I search for the `name=` and get the value after `=` ?

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I even tried that, No chance,
I tried : 
           `if(in_array("name=", $my_array)) { 
               echo 'Thats it';    
           } else { 
               echo 'not found !';
           }`

Comment: can you print_r your array and check if `name=` exists?

Comment: Yeah, i did it.And it was there : 
 `[1037] => name=ioio`

Comment: if that is the case then `in_array` wont work. The answer below is what you need. either you play around with `strpos` or `stristr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose in your array value is not `name=` exactly. It can be `name=something` for example. In this case neither `==` nor `in_array` will find it. You need to use `strpos`:

```
foreach($my_array as $cat) {
    $cat = trim($cat);
    if(strpos($cat, "name=") === 0) { 
        echo "hoola !", $cat;

        // add a break if value found so as not to search other elements
        break;
    } else { 
        echo ':-(';
    }
}
```

I used `===` and `0` because `name=` must be in the beginning of your `$cat`.

Comment: No chance, now it displays : 
`:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-( :-( ` ......

Comment: So if `name` is 1037th element then obviously it's somewhere deep inside this code. Do not echo `:-(` and see the results.

Comment: I just changed `===` 0 to `!== false` and it worked !

Comment: Returns FALSE if the needle was not found. - strpos documentation: [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)